# System.Data.SqlServerCe.HashSafeHandle" could not release handle with value 0x08D7E430

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce

I am getting this error:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.HashSafeHandle" could not release handle with value 0x08D7E430
```

suddenly using

```
System.Data.SqlServer_Ce_unofficial
```

and then calling this simple function (which worked all the time):

```
    Using nCmdSel As SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand = uCn.CreateCommand
        With nCmdSel
            .CommandText = uCommandText
        End With

        Dim r As SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader = nCmdSel.ExecuteReader
        Return r

    End Using
```

Does anybody have any idea why?

Comment: What is System.Data.SqlServer_Ce_unofficial ??

Comment: @It's by Microsoft. Official unofficial.